# JQuery/Spring: How to POST JSON but return html

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

When I post a JSON to the server and return a normal View string from the Spring controller, my jQuery is not hitting the "success" function.

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = MappingConstants.RULE_ASSIGNMENT, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveRuleAssignment(@RequestBody RuleAssignmentCO ruleAssignment) {
 // Some controller logic ...

 return "redirect:/some/view";
}
```

As you can see, my controller is simply taking in a JSON object, and returning a String view which is supposed to be parsed by Spring.  In my logs, I can see that the view is indeed being hit, but my jQuery post method is not hitting the "success" (nor the "error") function.

My jQuery:

```
jQuery.ajax({
 url: 'ruleAssignment',
 type: 'POST',
 cache: false,
 dataType: 'html',
 data: test,
 contentType: 'application/json',
 error: function() {
  console.log('error');
 },
 success: function() {
  console.log('success');
 }
});
```

Comment: I *think* it is because you are doing a redirect.  Generally, I forward to the view. I don't currently have an environment where I can test that theory, however.

Comment: You were right!  If I return the same view without a redirect it works fine.  I'm used to redirecting after a post, but that's kind of pointless when the post is an Ajax call.  Submit your comment as an answer and I'll vote you up one :)

Comment: Add @ResponseBody above method signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I perform a redirect with Spring (prepending "redirect:" before my View), the success method within the javascript ajax call will never get hit.

Usually I redirect after a "post" so I don't have to worry about the user hitting Refresh, but since it's an Ajax call it's unnecessary.

Thanks Gregg for the answer.